Solution of ODE does not reach the boundary of set
Consider $\dot x(t)=f(x(t))$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is sufficiently smooth (analytic).
Moreover, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\partial S$, where $S\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ is an open set.
Show that for $x(0)\in S$, the solution of the ODE does not reach $\partial S$ in finite time.

Apply uniqueness.

the vector field vanishes only at the boundary of the set, but not in its interior...

$S$ is not the domain of the ODE, in fact, as no domain is given it is presumably all of $\Bbb R^n$. So $\partial S$ is inside the domain.

As said, you should be more precisely in what ``sufficently smooth'' means in your context...and the domain of definition of $f$...If the function is defined on an open neighborhood of $S$ and the it is locally Lipschitz in this open set, the suggested uniqueness result applies. Possible ''counter-example''/limiting case: $S=(0,1)$ and $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=-\sqrt x$.

OK, I have modified the question. Now it is more precise... Indeed we can apply uniqueness in this case. Thank you very much.
